# How to get value inside many regex keys?

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to get the values ​​that are in braces as below:

```
{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{value1 here!}}}}}}}}}}}{value2 here!}}}}}}}}}{value3 here!}}}}}}
```

I would like you to be selected as a group:

```
{value1 here!} {value2 here!} {value3 here!}
```

I'm doing the expression on the site [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/23sVIZ/4) and applying it to my Java project.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\\\{.*\\\\}");
Matcher m = p.matcher("{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{value1 here!}}}}}}}}}}}{value2 here!}}}}}}}}}{value3 here!}}}}}}");
if (m.find()){
    String value1 = m.group(1);
    String value2 = m.group(2);
    String value3 = m.group(3);
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/23sVIZ/5

Comment: `m.group(3)` suggests that you confuse *match* with *group*. Also your `.*}` will match everything it can, until last `}`.Maybe use `[^}]*}` instead.

Comment: My question has nothing to do with the above association. The one that is associated with mine addresses another path ¯\(°_o)/¯

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need your glob match to match on non-brace characters:

```
\{[^{}]*\}
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/23sVIZ/5)

---

This is accomplished by using the construct `[^...]` for negated character classes which matches all characters except the ones specified within the `[^` and `]` delimiters